# How do i simplify this conditional logic in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So here is the situation i don't want to have to write `doA` twice...and i feel it should be possible to achieve that without resorting to functions.

How can i do it?

Also i remember reading on SO about labels to do something like this. Can you show me how's that done.

```
if (condition)
    if (condition)
        ...
    else if (condition)
        ...
    else
        doA
else 
    doA
```

The code above simply says this:

if true then (if true (...) else if true (...) else doA) else doA.. so it's like i want main if's else to run in some situations that come inside main if.

Comment: And why would you want to simplify it? Also if you're calling the same function irrespective of the condition, why do you need it in the first place?

Comment: [Don't use labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Avoid_using_labels).

Comment: @AmitJoki i call this function in very limited condition only if condition 1 fails OR condition 1 pass but both cond2 & cond3 fail.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (conditionA)
    if (conditionB)
        ...
    else if (conditionC)
        ...
    else
        doA
else 
    doA
```

can be

```
if (conditionA && condition B)

else if (conditionA && conditionC)

else 
    doA
```

Comment: this completely suits my comment above `only if condition A fails OR condition A pass but both condB & condC fail`

Comment: `if (conditionA && !(condtionB || conditionC)) doA` this what i'd have done if there was nothing for other conditions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this...

```
var a = <condition a>,
    b = <condition b>,
    c = <condition c>,
    doDoA = true;

if (a) {
    if (b) {
        doB;
        doDoA = false;
    } else if (c) {
        doC;
        doDoA = false;
    }
}

if (doDoA) {
    doA
}
```